# To keep count and save in Android app

Tags: android

I am making  an app which has different activities. each activity keeps a count of how many times the screen was tapped. i want to save the total number of counts of all activities separately (means i tap activity 1 10 times, it should save 10. Next time i tap it 5 times, the app should save 10+5=15 for activity 1)

the activities on tap just do a simple

```
count++;
```

how can implement this easily?
im new to android development
thanking you in advance :)

Comment: take one static int variable in mainActivity & increase its value as per tap on activity

Comment: @Sohaib Jamal store the count value in sharedPreferences and when next time activity opens get the stored value and add tap counts in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the counts in a persistent state using preferences. If you use static variables, the background activities may get destroyed when other apps take higher priority (eg press home and leave it for a long time before restore the app) and all your values will be wiped out when memory runs low.

```
SharedPreferences countSettings = getSharedPreferences("count", 0);

// get current counts
int count = countSettings.getInt("counts",0);
count++;
final SharedPreferences.Editor edit = countSettings.edit();
edit.putInt("counts",count);
edit.commit();
```

Comment: what if i want to display the count in a new activity?
ill have to do that via intent's put extra?
or is there another simpler way?

Comment: The SharedPreferences can be accessed anywhere in your activity. You don't need to pass the value around, just call the first two lines `SharedPreferences countSettings = getSharedPreferences("count", 0);` `int count = countSettings.getInt("counts",0);`.

Answer (score 0):

implement `OnTouchListener` for the root tag and in

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent touchevent) {
        count++;
        return true;
    }
```

in your `onDestroy`method store it in preference.

Comment: @Sohaib Jamal here is the link http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html
  
 to shared preference example